# Loading a directory from resource file and loading files into a list

Tags: java, scala

I am unable to locate the directory when calling getClass.getResource()

the path is src -> main -> resources -> RocheFiles

I have tried the absolute path. I currently have 39 csv files within the RocheFiles directory.

```
val testCaseDirectory = getClass.getResource("/RocheFiles")
    val directory = new File(testCaseDirectory.getPath)
    val testCases = if (directory.exists && directory.isDirectory) {
        directory
        .list
        .map(s => new File(directory.getAbsolutePath + "/" + s))
        .filter(s => s.exists && s.isDirectory)
        .sortBy(f => f.getName)
        .toList
    } else List.empty

    println(testCaseDirectory)
    println(directory)
    println(testCases)
```

Here is the println results:

```
jar:file:/var/folders/yr/tvnq7crd3mvdn0s3kyv_q4t00000gn/T/sbt_43463083/job-10/target/d5caefa1/rocheapp_2.12-0.1.0.jar!/RocheFiles
file:/var/folders/yr/tvnq7crd3mvdn0s3kyv_q4t00000gn/T/sbt_43463083/job-10/target/d5caefa1/rocheapp_2.12-0.1.0.jar!/RocheFiles
List()
List()
```

I have tried

```
val testCaseDirectory = getClass.getResource("/RocheFiles")
    val directory = new File(testCaseDirectory.getPath)

    // for c,d,e,f
    val cdef = directory.listFiles.toList
               .filter(_.isDirectory)
               .flatMap(p => new File(p.getPath).listFiles)

    println(cdef)
```

still getting null pointer exception

```
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Oct 12, 2019, 12:55:09 AM
sbt:rocheApp> run
[error] (run-main-c) java.lang.NullPointerException
[error] java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I am able to pull 1 file at a time directly - using this: Unsure on how to read in the directory and iterate through each CSV file.

```
override def readRoche(): List[List[String]] = {
    for {
      line <- Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines().toList
      values = line.split('|').toList
    } yield values}
}
```

This is the execution of CSVReader.

```
val rocheLines = new CSVReader("src/main/resources/RocheFiles/BP40331_UBSC_QRS3_PROD_OPEN_20190926121416.csv").readRoche()
```

UPDATE:  I moved the directory outside of the resources directory and I am able to read in the csv's using code below

```
def getListOfFiles(dir: String):List[File] = {
        val d = new File(dir)
        if (d.exists && d.isDirectory) {
            d.listFiles.filter(_.isFile).toList
        } else {
            List[File]()
        }
}
```

```
val testCaseDirectory = getListOfFiles("src/main/scala/corp/marshconsult/bracketProjects/rocheApp/RocheFiles")
```

Still unsure as to why I am able to locate individual files within the resources directory, but not a directory inside of the resources directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `listFiles` to list all objects and `isFile` or `isDirectory` to determine file or folder.

If the dir structure looks like this

```
- main
-- resources
--- RocheFiles
---- a.txt
---- b.txt
---- dir1
----- c.txt
----- d.txt
---- dir2
----- e.txt
----- f.txt
```

to get those files would simply be

```
  val testCaseDirectory = getClass.getResource("/RocheFiles")
  val directory = new File(testCaseDirectory.getPath)

  // for a,b files
  val ab = directory.listFiles.filter(_.isFile)

  // for c,d,e,f
  val cdef = directory.listFiles.toList
             .filter(_.isDirectory)
             .flatMap(p => new File(p.getPath).listFiles)
```

Comment: I ran those for c,d,e,f and am still getting a Null Pointer exception - @inmyth

Comment: val directory = new File(testCaseDirectory.getPath) this is getting the NPE.

Comment: In other word `val testCaseDirectory = getClass.getResource("/RocheFiles")` is null. You need to check for typos or if that dir exists at the right place

Comment: It's getting copied into the target directory under scala-2.12 -> classes -> RocheFiles  - Plus when I run the absolute path to one of the csv files it works.

Comment: Yes it is the correct behavior. Stuff in resources folder will be copied to the built directory for runtime execution.